# File validation on XPages

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I am working on application in XPages and I need to do file upload validation on the server side.
I read that file upload only works on client side, so I tried to validate another filed that stores file name attached. I did it on the on change event of the file upload. The problem occurs when I delete an attached file- there is no on change event on file download control… any suggestions? Or maybe different way? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsaved list of attachments can be accessed from the `getAttachmentList("RTFieldName")` method of the data source.

I suggest using a hidden input and custom validator to have more control, like:

```
<xp:message
    id="message1"
    for="inputHidden1"></xp:message>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:inputHidden
    id="inputHidden1"
    value="arbitrary">
    <xp:this.validators>
        <xp:customValidator>
            <xp:this.validate><![CDATA[{javascript:
     // RTField the name of the rich text field that holds attachments
   if(document1.getAttachmentList("RTField").size()==0) {
      // You might want to do more checks here.
      var inputHidden1 = getComponent("inputHidden1");
      inputHidden1.setValid(false);
      return "You have to upload a file!" // your error message
}}]]></xp:this.validate>
        </xp:customValidator>
    </xp:this.validators>
</xp:inputHidden>
```

Remember, `value="arbitrary"` is important. Empty fields will not trigger custom validators.